# Implementing a callback after user registration

Tags: 7, users

I want to run a database query in another CRM database after a user has registered. I have the following function in my sugar_crm module eg:

```
function sugar_crm_user_register_submit($form, &$form_state)
{       
    // some code to run a database query in SugarCRM
    ddl("User registration form submitted to CRM");         

}
```

However, the function doesn't appear ever to be called. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is your drupal version 6 or 7?

Comment: My current version is Drupal 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A way is add a `submit` function to `user_register_form` submits in form alter.

```
yourmodule_form_alter(&$from,$form_state,$form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form ) { 
       $form['#submit'][] = 'sugar_crm_user_register_submit';
       }
 }
```

but I think the better way is setup your custom function in `hook_user_insert`.this hook triggered when a user registered . you can implement it in your custom module.

```
  function yourmodule_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
   // some code to run a database query in SugarCRM
  ddl("User registration form submitted to CRM"); 
  }
```

Comment: hook_user_insert was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. I guess I just need to become more familiar with the API!

Comment: Yes. working with drupal needs familiarity with drupal api. I pleasured could help you. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
function sugar_crm_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {

  // some code to run a database query in SugarCRM

    ddl("User registration form submitted to CRM");  
}
```

This code worked for me in D7.

For D6,

```
function scrm_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {

  if ($op == 'insert' || $op == 'update' )  {

  // some code to run a database query in SugarCRM

    ddl("User registration form submitted to CRM"); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the '#submit' property inside your hook_form_alter() ? 
E.g

```
 <?php 
    function sugar_crm_form_alter(){
// Call the  submit handler    
$form['#submit'][] = 'sugar_crm_user_register_submit';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I didn't. I've added that in now, and the _user_register_submit function still doesn't get called.

Comment: Right, I think I've worked it out. I needed to define the $form in the function signature. EG sugar_crm_form_alter(&$form)