# how to use hook_user_login to catch username and password

Tags: hooks, users

I am trying to catch the username and password which are entered on the user login form. This is my code:

```
function impak_integration_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  drupal_set_message("Welcome User!" . print_r($edit). print_r($account));
  global $user;
  drupal_set_message(print_r($user));
  }
```

The hook does work, as It does print out the Welcome message after login. However, I can't figure out how to get any of the user information, specifically the entered username and password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information send in the login form is in the $edit array. You can get this information as follows:

```
function YOURMODULE_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  $username = $edit['input']['name'];
  $password = $edit['input']['pass'];
  drupal_set_message("Welcome $username your password is $password");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But I dont understand why - my printout from the above message was Welcome User!11
1 - every print_r returned a '1'. Why?

Comment: I'm not sure why print_r would return '1', but I strongly recommend you to use dpm() function which ships with [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module. You can use it like: `dpm($edit)` instead of `drupal_set_message(print_r($edit))`

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. - The [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) function has a second parameter which must be used if you wish to return the output. The proper syntax for the OP would be `print_r($account,TRUE)` to see the content of the $account object.

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know that, thanks! I see the reason why I normally don't need that parameter, I just do a a print. But now, I am doing the print_r inside of the drupal_set_message, so I needed to have print_r actually return the output to drupal_set_message, not actually print it.

Answer (score 1):

Think twice why you need to do something before login! As one of the possible answer
- In order to catch the user login, you can implement hook_form_alter() as below

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_login_block':
    case 'user_login' :
      array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'custom_login_submit');
      break;
  }
}

/**
* Custom submit handler
*/
function custom_login_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  //code here
  dpm($form_state);
}
```

clearly you will get both things in $formstate

The reason you might not be getting pass in hook_user_login() is because it is called after login.

Comment: Can you explain your code a little better? I originally was going to do hook_form_alter, following this post http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41782/implementing-a-callback-after-user-registration. However, I couldn't get it to work. What exactly is your array_unshift doing and why does it work?

Comment: it makes your submit handler to act before the drupal default, keeping all other handlers intact

Comment: Can you give the submit handler any name you want? Does it have to end with 'submit'?

Comment: you can give it any name but better to give which make sense